# Angular 6 webcomponents. Angular element in Angular app not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have problem with run angular element in angular app.
I have simple app with simple component. AppModule:

```js
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ChangeDetectorRef, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {TestComponent} from './test/test.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {ButtonModule, DropdownModule, InputTextModule} from "primeng/primeng";
import {Test2Component} from './test2/test2.component';
import {createCustomElement} from "@angular/elements";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    Test2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    DropdownModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [TestComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const TestElement = createCustomElement(TestComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('appd-test', TestElement);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
  }
}
```

test.component.ts:

```js
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {SelectItem} from "primeng/api";

@Component({
  selector: 'appd-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class TestComponent {
  
  _message;
  _message2;
  
  cars: SelectItem[] = [
    {label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi'},
    {label: 'BMW', value: 'BMW'},
    {label: 'Fiat', value: 'Fiat'},
    {label: 'Ford', value: 'Ford'},
    {label: 'Honda', value: 'Honda'},
    {label: 'Jaguar', value: 'Jaguar'},
    {label: 'Mercedes', value: 'Mercedes'},
    {label: 'Renault', value: 'Renault'},
    {label: 'VW', value: 'VW'},
    {label: 'Volvo', value: 'Volvo'},
  ];
  
  _selectedCar: string;
  set selectedCar(value: string) {
    this._selectedCar = value;
  }
  
  set message(value) {
    this._message = value;
    console.log(value);
  }
  
  set message2(value) {
    this._message2 = value;
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

test.component.html:

```html
<div>
  <h1>TEST1</h1>

  <div>
    <span>Name: </span>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="_message" pInputText />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Surname: </span>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message2" pInputText />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p-dropdown  [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar"></p-dropdown>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>{{_message}}</span>
    <span>{{_message2}}</span>
    <span>{{_selectedCar}}</span>
  </div>
  <h2>......................</h2>
</div>
```

After ng build I have 5 files: main.js, polyfills.js, runtime.js, styles.js, vendor.js.

I another angular app I want to import this webcomponent.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <appd-test></appd-test> <!-- HERE WORKS, inside app-root NOT WORKING -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/appd/runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/appd/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/appd/styles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/appd/vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/appd/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I putted in this webcomponent into app.component.html of new angular app events not working  - _message and _message2 inputs wasn't showing nothing on the screen.
When I putted test webcomponent directly into index.html everything was ok.

Does anybody has got any suggestions what's going on?

Comment: Why can't you import the feature module into your main module and include it in your templates? Are there any challenges in doing so?

Comment: Yes, I know I can import module in the angular way (import module), but I want to be independent of the technology. In the future I want to import also ReactJS, VueJS etc so I can't just import module, I have to import only javascript in the webcomponents way (like I mentioned above).

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: I think this works against the nature of the Opinionated Framework that is Angular.  I appreciate wanting the freedom to choose which Framework but you're setting yourself for a maintenance nightmare.  Angular is going to need to upgraded every couples years to maintain support... I'd avoid this idea.